# how to move splash screen left-right (android)

Tags: android, splash-screen

I'm new to android development, I'm working on a wallpaper app in which I'm implementing a splash screen.

I want to move the splash screen left-right/ right-left while it is displaying. 
Please note: I'm not talking about changing/sliding the image, I want to move the displaying image.

Please see this below video it explains what I want: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2c8j8e_scr-20141210-183228_school

I don't know how to move the splash screen. so please help.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.usd.amazingwallpapershd.R;
import com.usd.amazingwallpapershd.app.AppConst;
import com.usd.amazingwallpapershd.app.AppController;
import com.usd.amazingwallpapershd.picasa.model.Category;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String TAG_FEED = "feed", TAG_ENTRY = "entry",
            TAG_GPHOTO_ID = "gphoto$id", TAG_T = "$t",
            TAG_ALBUM_TITLE = "title";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        ////splash images array
        // Randomise a background
        int[] yourListOfImages= {R.drawable.splash_1, R.drawable.splash_2, R.drawable.splash_3, R.drawable.splash_4, R.drawable.splash_5, R.drawable.splash_6,R.drawable.splash_7};

        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int posOfImage = random.nextInt(yourListOfImages.length - 1);

        ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_imageview);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(yourListOfImages[posOfImage]);
        ////

        // Picasa request to get list of albums
        String url = AppConst.URL_PICASA_ALBUMS
                .replace("_PICASA_USER_", AppController.getInstance()
                        .getPrefManger().getGoogleUserName());

        Log.d(TAG, "Albums request url: " + url);

        // Preparing volley's json object request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url,
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Albums Response: " + response.toString());
                        List<Category> albums = new ArrayList<Category>();
                        try {
                            // Parsing the json response
                            JSONArray entry = response.getJSONObject(TAG_FEED)
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_ENTRY);

                            // loop through albums nodes and add them to album
                            // list
                            for (int i = 0; i < entry.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject albumObj = (JSONObject) entry.get(i);
                                // album id
                                String albumId = albumObj.getJSONObject(
                                        TAG_GPHOTO_ID).getString(TAG_T);

                                // album title
                                String albumTitle = albumObj.getJSONObject(
                                        TAG_ALBUM_TITLE).getString(TAG_T);

                                Category album = new Category();
                                album.setId(albumId);
                                album.setTitle(albumTitle);

                                // add album to list
                                albums.add(album);

                                Log.d(TAG, "Album Id: " + albumId
                                        + ", Album Title: " + albumTitle);
                            }

                            // Store albums in shared pref
                            AppController.getInstance().getPrefManger()
                                    .storeCategories(albums);

                            // String the main activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            // closing spalsh activity
                            finish();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Volley Error: " + error.getMessage());

                        // show error toast
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                getString(R.string.splash_error),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Unable to fetch albums
                        // check for existing Albums data in Shared Preferences
                        if (AppController.getInstance().getPrefManger()
                                .getCategories() != null
                                && AppController.getInstance().getPrefManger()
                                        .getCategories().size() > 0) {
                            // String the main activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            // closing spalsh activity
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // Albums data not present in the shared preferences
                            // Launch settings activity, so that user can modify
                            // the settings

                            // Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                            // SettingsActivity.class);
                            // // clear all the activities
                            // i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            // | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            // startActivity(i);

                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    SplashActivity.this).create();
                            alertDialog
                                    .setMessage("Please connect to the internet and try again");
                            alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    });
                            alertDialog.show();

                        }

                    }
                });

        // disable the cache for this request, so that it always fetches updated
        // json
        jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);

        // Making the request
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to load a wallpaper image and then autoscroll it. If you haven't already, you can find multiple templates for the class that extends `WallpaperService`. You'll also see examples where a Handler+Runnable is used to repeatedly call `draw` within the class -- this gives you your animation. Now all you need to do is make the clip bounds of the canvas that's created with the class wider than your screen dimension. Something like

```
Rect fullBoundsRect = c.getClipBounds();
fullBoundsRect.inset(-tilew, 0); //make the canvas bounds wider
```

will do that for you.

Then you just need to draw a bitmap that's larger than your screen bounds (using `canvas.drawBitmap`) and use a `Matrix` operation to iteratively move it across the screen.

If you use a large bitmap, you will have to carefully manage memory (you might have to load it in cropped portions instead -- the `drawBitmap` command give you some options for that, in which case you wouldn't need to bother with widening the Canvas bounds), but this gives you the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to animate your background. We can take canvas and draw image continuously by moving the image to respective direction. See this blog post, it may help you.

[Animating Background Image](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-game-development-moving-or.html)

Answer (score 0):

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.tst2.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_animation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/wal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="66dp"
        android:text="Background Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    ImageView img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_animation);
    
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
      0.0f, 0.0f);
    animation.setDuration(5000);
    animation.setRepeatCount(5);
    // if you want infinite
    // animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    animation.setRepeatMode(2);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    img_animation.startAnimation(animation);

    }
}
```

Comment: well thanks, but it's going out of image size. move only according to image size. don't move out of image size.

Comment: Change the parameter list. TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)